# Changing Text with Fade Javascript Multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create my own website, where it has an initial quote in the center:
*"Welcome to my website"*, and when you hover over the **menu options**, the quote should change.
For example: if I hover over **About** it could say: *"This is my About me Page"*. (The example is obviously simplified).

HTML Snippet:

```
<a href="#" class="titleAbout">About</a>
<a href="#" class="titleContact">Contact</a>
<a href="#" class="titleHome">Home</a>
<div>
<p>
Welcome to my Website!
</p>
</div>
```

CSS Snippet:

```
.fade { 
  animation: fadein 2s;

}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

JS Snippet

```
let myP = document.querySelector('p');
let titleWords = document.querySelector('a.titleAbout');

titleWords.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    myP.classList.add("fade");
setTimeout(function(){
        myP.innerHTML = "This is my about Me page";
        }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
            text.classList.toggle("fade");
        }, 2000);
    });

titleWords = document.querySelector('a.titleContact');

titleWords.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    myP.classList.add("fade");
setTimeout(function(){
        myP.innerHTML = "This is my Contact page";
        }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
            text.classList.toggle("fade");
        }, 2000);
    });
```

However - it only does the fade properly the first time I hover over a menu item, the other times it changes the `innerHTML`, but doesn't fade in and out.

Why exactly is this happening an how can I fix it?

Comment: Two main points:
1) The example I gave is simplified as I still havent decided exactly what the new quote should be - but I want the option to change the whole sentence.
2) It still doesnt change the fact that the fade only happens once.

Comment: I guess you have multiple issues there: 
1. setTimeouts are ugly: do the first setTimeout with css (longer opacity 0), second timeout should move into `onMouseOut` to remove `fade` class
2. if you still have issues, instead of updating your containers, but remove them and append newly.

Comment: Can you provide a demo jsFiddle link ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/15kocfhr/3/

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined the `text` variable in your javascript. I think you mean `myP.classList.toggle("fade");`

```js
let myP = document.querySelector('p');
let titleWords = document.querySelector('a.titleAbout');

titleWords.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    myP.classList.add("fade");
setTimeout(function(){
        myP.innerHTML = "This is my about Me page";
        }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
            myP.classList.toggle("fade");
        }, 2000);
    });

titleWords = document.querySelector('a.titleContact');

titleWords.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    myP.classList.add("fade");
setTimeout(function(){
        myP.innerHTML = "This is my Contact page";
        }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
            myP.classList.toggle("fade");
        }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
.fade { 
  animation: fadein 2s;

}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="titleAbout">About</a>
<a href="#" class="titleContact">Contact</a>
<a href="#" class="titleHome">Home</a>
<div>
<p>
Welcome to my Website!
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it shorter and without `setTimeout`:

```js
let myP = document.querySelector('p');

function show(textToShow){
  myP.innerHTML = textToShow;
  myP.classList.add("fade");
}

function hide(){
 myP.classList.remove("fade");
}
```

```css
.fade { 
  animation: fadein 3s;

}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="titleAbout" onmouseenter="show('This is my about Me page')" onmouseout="hide()">About</a>
<a href="#" class="titleContact" onmouseenter="show('This is my contact Me page')" onmouseout="hide()">Contact</a>
<a href="#" class="titleHome">Home</a>
<div>
<p>
Welcome to my Website!
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code to a more generic version, so you can have as many links as you want and do not need to repeat your code. It takes a title attribute from the a tag as text. Maybe this behaves more like you intended, you can play around uncommenting that timeout.

```js
const myPContainer = document.getElementById('pContainer');
const titleWords = document.querySelectorAll('a');
let i;

function attachHandlers(i, elem) {
  let timeoutHandle;
  const pElem = document.createElement('p');
  pElem.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute('title');
  myPContainer.appendChild(pElem);

  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    timeoutHandle = null;
    pElem.classList.add("fadein");
  });

  elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    // timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      pElem.classList.remove("fadein");
    // }, 2000);
  });
  
}

for (i = 0; i < titleWords.length; ++i) {
  attachHandlers(i, titleWords[i]);
}
```

```css
#pContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
#pContainer p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fadein { 
  animation: fadein 2s;
  display: block;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="titleAbout" title="This is my about Me page">About</a>
<a href="#" class="titleContact" title="This is my Contact page">Contact</a>
<a href="#" class="titleHome" title="This is my Home page">Home</a>
<div id="pContainer"></div>
```